# Zimbra API sample

Tags: c#, zimbra

I have to create a module using c# to consume Zimbra Webservice (soap protocol)
I wonder if anybody has already done this kind of project (talking about the Zimbra part)?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find it here:

http://zimbra.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zimbra/trunk/ZimbraCSharpClient/

and how to use it ... here :

http://www.zimbra.com/forums/developers/14017-zimbra-csharp-client-library.html